# Couldn't use the same classname across components. CSS is not being scoped inside a style component

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styled-components, css-in-js

The problem I am having seems to defeat the very purpose of CSS in JS. I am using styled-compomnents. And when I tried to use a classname that is being used somewhere up in the react tree inside a styled component. The upper component classname styles somehow get applied to the classname I used down (very) the tree.

### Steps to reproduce

Render `UpperComponent` anywhere in a react project.

```
const StyledContainer = styled.div`
  .title {
    color: red;
    margin-bottom: 32px;
  }
`;

const UpperComponent = () => {
  return (
    <StyledContainer>
      <FirstComponent />
      <h4 className="title"> text inside upper component </h4>
    </StyledContainer>
  );
};


const FirstStyledContainer = styled.div``;

const FirstComponent = () => {
  return (
    <FirstStyledContainer>
      <h4 className="title">text inside first component</h4>
      <SecondComponent />
    </FirstStyledContainer>
  );
};

const SecondComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h4 className="title">text inside second component</h4>
      <ThirdComponent />
    </div>
  );
};

const ThirdComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h4 className="title">text inside second component </h4>
    </div>
  );
};
```

### Expected Behavior

`title` classname in the `UpperComponent` should not affect it's descendants' elements with the same classname. It should be scoped only to  `<h4 className="title"> text inside upper component </h4>`

### Actual Behavior

`.title { color: red; margin-bottom: 32px; }` class styles get applied to all the components inside UpperComponent. `title` somehow makes it down to `ThirdCompoent` which is nested inide two components.

Is this expected behavior or am I missing something basic (best practice)?

Comment: It is the expected behavior... And nothing to do with styled component, actually in CSS-in-JS you should not use classNames and use the library instead

Comment: But do you think every single element should be a styled component.

Comment: Try research what css-in-js comes to solve, which is exactly what you trying to do

Comment: I have split css/scss. Critical "above the fold" css/scss use styled components, anything "below the fold" i stick into a css/scss file to load afterwards. When it comes to styled components, sometimes i make a react component styled component and sometimes i make one specific to a element (but moslty a react component). I may also only include mobile scss/css in the styled component and place the desktop break point stuff in the scss/css file o be loaded later.

Answer (score 1):

If you want enforce the scoping - You can remove the class names and/or let "styled component" name them (generates a random hash class name) by creating a TitleStyle and attach to the title div (class name "title" can be removed). This should scope to that title only then. Right ?

Another alternative

Yes the FirstComponent and SecondComponent (etc) will catch the css rule from the top. This is the expected result for me. Its not like when we do this below !

```
<div style = {{color:"red"}}>Test</div>
```

This would apply the css inline to that div only.

I would slightly change the names of the title classes like so

```
const StyledContainer = styled.div`
  .title {
    color: red;
    margin-bottom: 32px;
    &.secondary { color: pink; }
    &.thirdly { color: yellow; }
  }
`;

const UpperComponent = () => {
  return (
    <StyledContainer>
      <FirstComponent />
      <h4 className="title"> text inside upper component </h4>
    </StyledContainer>
  );
};

const SecondComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h4 className="title secondary">text inside second component</h4>
      <ThirdComponent />
    </div>
  );
};

const ThirdComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h4 className="title thirdly">text inside second component </h4>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The & is a SCSS operator and works fine with styled components.
CSS is more benifical to behave this way as passing css rules down is more effecient. Work with this effeciency ! You want to create site wide CSS patterns, try avoid specific targeting unless your sure its required (Which should be not too common).

What I do moslty is, created a styled component for the react component, so one per react components to handle all css/scss in that react component.

Daniel

Comment: But doesn't this defeat the purpose of scoping in CSS in JS?

Comment: Check out my modified answer ? Let me know

Comment: Yeah, that pretty much works. But my concern is that the implicit styles that come from a parent styled component. Which could get out of hand because most class names are generic.

Comment: I did edit the answer again, make sure you have read the most recent answer. So to be clear. If you want a styled component to be specific to a div, you need make a TitleStyle and attach to that title. Thats makes unique random hash class name. It wont affect other titles. But preferably, re-use CSS, make site wide css. I did answer your question right ?

Answer (score 1):

This is working as it should. You're selecting all the `.title`s in that styled-component.

In the end, styled-components just generate a unique class name for every styled-component you made. So the rules of CSS still work there.

You can

1. You can select only the direct descendant `.title`.

```
    const StyledContainer = styled.div`
     >.title {
      // rules...
     }
    `
```

2. Change the class name to something more specific.
3. Nest the CSS rule on the parent. So instead of this,

```
    const StyledContainer = styled.div`
     .title {
      // rules...
     }
    `
```

Wrap your h4 with another element and do this

```
    const StyledContainer = styled.div`
      .wrapperClassName {
         .title {
          // rules...
         }
      }
    `
```

Comment: Creating a TitleStyle and attaching to the title div is more practical. This is an extra layer on unnecessary complexity I would have thought