# child css is being override by the parent

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm using Styled-Component in my React project. I noted that my Child component CSS is being overridden by its parent.

This is the Parent component and its Styled-Component Wrapper:

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import Child from "./Child";

const Parent = () => {
  return (
    <ParentWrapper>
      <div className="nice-box" />
      <Child />
    </ParentWrapper>
  );
};

const ParentWrapper = styled.div`
  .nice-box {
    border: 3px solid black;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
  }
`;

export default Parent;
```

And this is the Child component:

```
    import styled from "styled-components";

const Child = () => {
  return (
    <ChildWrapper>
      <div className="nice-box" />
    </ChildWrapper>
  );
};

const ChildWrapper = styled.div`
  .nice-box {
    border: 3px solid green;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
  }
`;

export default Child;
```

And this is the result:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5I8a.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Couldn't use the same classname across components. CSS is not being scoped inside a style component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64715666/couldnt-use-the-same-classname-across-components-css-is-not-being-scoped-insid)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is, use the class names and apply the style to those classes only. That's all.

Answer (score -1):

its like all class was applied one style, you must defined which class will be used that style